# Call a function on an element in Javascript

Tags: javascript, function, function-call

I'm trying to create a JS library, and I'd like to call it/initialize it the *JQuery* way:

```
$('.el').myLibrary({opts});
```

How can I achieve this? What sort of shenanigan I have to do?

Thanks for the help

Edit: I'm not using Jquery, I just want to have the same sort of mechanism in order to initialize my library, but I can't get my head around it.

More specifically, I want it to be called with Form elements, so for example:

```
document.getElementById('someForm').myLibrary({})
```

So then I am able to get the form element with the this argument in my library.

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/jquery.fn.extend/

Comment: You need two functions. `$( '.el' )` is a function that returns an object with multiple functions and the scope as the elements matching the selector. Then you can call the methods attached to that object and it will use the scope in the methods.

Comment: Please read the EDIT, and unmark it as duplicate.